# Access: reset the values in value lists to 0 after closing form

Tags: ms-access

I have a form with value lists in which the user can write down numbers, and these numbers are used in query calculations.

When I close the form after entering the numbers and running the queries, I would like the values shown in particular value lists to reset to 0. Instead, the previous user input is shown.

I did some googling and found several posts offering solutions using code (javascript etc, for example here http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-reset-form.phtml) . I'm not familiar with this code and struggle on understanding it, let alone implement it. I was wondering if anyone has a different method (such as queries, which I do understand) to achieve what I need, or could possibly guide me in the right direction.

Below is a screenshot of the data tab of the property sheet of one of the value lists.I was trying to find a way to reset to a default value using one of the rows there but so far no luck.

[image]

Picture added to show where users exactly enter the information. For example - user wrote down 40 and 1500 for aluminum.

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, the users are adding items to the value list for the listboxes?

Comment: @random_answer_guy, I believe so if I understand your question well. I added a picture to explain where users enter the info.

Comment: Just confused why you would use listbox for this? In any event, can you not simply set the listbox Value List to zero, `Me.List41.Rowsouce = "0"` ?

Comment: What would be a better box to use? I'm not aware of all advantages or disadvantages of using list boxes

Comment: Unless I'm missing something wouldn't a simple textbox work the same. Unless they are entering multiple items which it appears they are not, a textbox would be the easiest. Here is a good listbox [LISTBOX](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-27.html)

Comment: The user input image does not reconcile with implied use of listbox. I do not see any listboxes, just textboxes. Are these textboxes bound to table fields? If not and you want to set to 0 without closing form, use code to set value of textbox.